# searching for a space opera novel with a planet of monks who controlled a monopoly on functional immortality via plant-based biotech

Tags: story-identification, novel, immortality, symbiotes, plants

A space opera novel with a planet whose inhabitants are a group of 'monks' with a quasi-religious monopoly on functional immortality. There's a parasitic/symbiotic plant organism (I don't remember if it was microbial  algae or a multicellular parasite or if it was sentient or not) native  to said planet which can meddle with the biology of its host, fixing any  damage, but only the monks have figured out how to communicate  with/control it, so if anyone other than them tries to use it, they'll  die horribly of parasitic plant growth body horror. The monks have leveraged said  power into various demands, including the establishment of a quasi-serf  caste of offworld prospective immortality seekers. A couple decades of  servitude in exchange for being allowed to leave and live forever. The book was written in english and it was fairly old.

Comment: Some matches with the *Hyperion* books by Dan Simmons, but some differences.

Comment: Specifically the third book, *Endymion*.

Comment: Nah, that wasn't it, if only as a matter of scale. Hyperion's Pax church was a galaxy wide superpower, this was just a one-planet civilization.

Comment: How old is "fairly old?"  15 years?

Comment: Sounds Jack-Vance-ian but I can't place it.

Comment: [The Eyes of Heisenberg](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2015.The_Eyes_of_Heisenberg)?

Comment: Sorry, I'm still pretty sure that wasn't it either. No monks, the biotech immortality is a treatment rather than a symbiotic plant and entirely set on earth.